# Enable button only if at-least one CheckBox is checked using Stimulus JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am using Rails 7 and in one of my forms i have multiple check-boxes. how can make the submit button disabled until at-least one Checkbox is checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using some vanilla JS along with Web API and Stimulus you can get a proper solution.

This is my test ERB form (using Tailwind for convenience):

```
<%= form_with data: {controller: "test"} do |form| %>
  <div id="checkboxes">
    <div>
      <%= form.check_box :option_a, data: { "action" => "test#change" } %>
      <%= form.label :option_a %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= form.check_box :option_b, data: { "action" => "test#change" } %>
      <%= form.label :option_b %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= form.check_box :option_c, data: { "action" => "test#change" } %>
      <%= form.label :option_c %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= form.submit :save,
  class: "rounded-md border border-gray-800 bg-white mt-4 py-2 px-4 text-sm disabled:text-gray-200 disabled:border-gray-200",
  disabled: true,
  data: { "test-target" => "button" } %>
<% end %>
```

In the controller, looking for the `checked` attribute of every checkbox every time any of them changes (gets either checked or unchecked) would suffice. The controller could look like this:

```js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

// Connects to data-controller="test"
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["button"]

  connect() {}

  change(event) {
    console.log(event.target.checked);
    const optionChosen = Array.from(
      event.target.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("input")).filter((input) =>
        input.type === "checkbox" && input.checked
      )
    if (optionChosen.length > 0) {
      this.buttonTarget.disabled = false;
    } else {
      this.buttonTarget.disabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution because I am a newbie - but it works :)

Let me know if you solved this problem somehow differently.

```
 #show.html.erb

    <%= form_with(url: your_path) do |f| %>
       <div data-controller="disable">
             <div>
                <%= f.check_box :test, { checked: false, data: { action: "change->disable#next" } } %>
             </div>
             <div>
                <%= f.check_box :test2, { checked: false, data: { action: "change->disable#next" } } %>
             </div>
             <div class="mb-10">
                <%= f.submit "Submit!", class: 
                   "w-full
                   rounded-md
                   bordder-primary
                   py-3
                   px-5
                   bg-primary
                   text-base text-white
                   cursor-pointer
                   hover:bg-opacity-90
                   transition", id: 'submit' 
                %>
             </div>
       </div>

<% end %>
```

And:

```
 #app/javascript/controllers/disable_controller.js

    import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
    
    export default class extends Controller {
      connect() {
        document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
      }
      
      next(event) {
        var x = (document.getElementById("test").checked);
        var y = (document.getElementById("test2").checked);
        if (x == true || y == true) {
          document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your response but in my form my check-boxes are generated automatically. even though this is a really good idea it is not applicable for my case. Plus i am using Stimulus Component select all check boxes.